# Data doesn't fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

can some one tell me why my neural network doesn't fit ys when I test any value in xs??
and can someone plot it for me please

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", name="layer7"),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu", name="layer8"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, name="layer9"),
])
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mae'])
a= float(input("enter the wanted value to convert : "))
xs=np.array([443707.401,455897.072,
396833.899,407426.699,435646.069,
419953.188,436349.443,633372.629,
572704.102,506379.29,596808.359,
622705.893,521749.843,500965.861,
558482.399,672648.564,739873.87,
459092.199,485007.612,579586.959,
509713.739,725009.687,727394.13,
658740.26,485686.823,461640.1,502495.219,
625584.252,680222.202,760907.585,
738381.47,712415.6], dtype=float)

ys=np.array([443417.925,455608.023,
397588.538,407135.987,435356.29,
419662.842,436059.613,633089.564,
572418.983,506091.937,596524.026,
622422.445,521463.004,500678.296,
558196.649,672366.797,739594.302,
458803.188,484719.43,579302.029,
509426.339,724729.561,727114.01,
658457.788,485398.691,461351.171,
502207.616,625300.699,679940.373,
760628.252,738101.41,712134.732],dtype=float)

model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=298,verbose=1)

result= (model.predict([a]))
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ??....also u didn't define `model` anywhere in the code before compiling it ? I guess that's a typing mistake....but can you just print the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have xs and ys, then I assume your code was meant to look something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
model.compile('RMSprop','mse',metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=298,verbose=1)
```

This is highly unlikely to converge to the answer you are looking for. In particular, your data very easily fits a linear equation in 2 variables. This model has 81 random variables that are slowly being adjusted to try and lower the MSE. The 81 dimensional plot does not care in the slightest that there is a single (best) solution out there somewhere. It only knows that slight adjustments in your random variables to lower the MSE a little bit, if it can even out the error amongst the data. Hence, this model converges to predict the exact same value for all inputs.

After you run the model above and wait for it to finish training, you can explore your model. For example,

```
model.summary()                  #print the summary of the layers and variables
print(model.predict(xs))         #print all the predictions for all the xs

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xs,ys)                  #Graph what your current data looks like
plt.plot(xs,model.predict(xs))   #Graph what your model is predicting
```

In general, a tensorflow model is not intended to find single precise solutions; it is intended to estimate a possible solution that may or may not do a good job at predicting. In general, a keras model is expected to work with 10,000 of variables to try and find an approximate answer to a prediction problem. Consider this in sharp contrast to use a direct formula, like:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.linregress(xs,ys)
```

The precise formula above finds THE exact slope and y-int that produce THE smallest Mean Squared Error.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Bobby, I really stack in this code and it is a big problem for me